# How to solve terraform error for configuring local aws credentials?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using below code to for configuring aws creds.

```
provider "aws"  {
    region  = var.region_name
    profile = "default"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.76"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}
```

I was getting below error whenever we run `terraform plan`

Error:

```
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│ 
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│
│ Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
│ caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
│ SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, default.
│ EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
│ caused by: RequestError: send request failed
│ caused by: Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried upgrading my aws provider version as per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#changes-to-authentication and it started working as below:

```
provider "aws"  {
    region  = var.region_name
    profile = "default"
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have configuration files (e.g., ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config) setup correctly if you want to use `profile`.

Otherwise you can set it up with

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

And pass the secrets e.g via [variable sets in terraform cloud](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/cloud-get-started/cloud-create-variable-set).

Answer (score 0):

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#changes-to-authentication

Please read below carefully

In previous versions of the provider, you could explicitly set profile in the provider, and if the profile did not correspond to valid credentials, the provider would use credentials from environment variables. Starting in v4.0, the Terraform AWS provider enforces the precedence shown above, similarly to how the AWS SDK and AWS CLI behave.

In other words, when you explicitly set profile in provider, the AWS provider will not use environment variables per the precedence shown above. Before v4.0, if profile was configured in the provider configuration but did not correspond to an AWS profile or valid credentials, the provider would attempt to use environment variables. This is no longer the case. An explicitly set profile that does not have valid credentials will cause an authentication error.